# loading a large CSV file and setting index (0-n) in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I load a csv file in the following manner

```
df = dd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/cars.csv', \
                 sep=';', blocksize="10KB", \
                 dtype={'Car': str},skiprows=[1])
```

This breaks the file into p partitions. How do I set index using the set_index function? The indices I want are 0-n if there are n+1 rows in the csv file.

Divisions is defined as the following in this [link](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html)

> Note that len(divisons) is equal to npartitions + 1. This is because divisions represents the upper and lower bounds of each partition. The first item is the lower bound of the first partition, the second item is the lower bound of the second partition and the upper bound of the first partition, and so on. The second-to-last item is the lower bound of the last partition, and the last (extra) item is the upper bound of the last partition.

I calculate the divisions based on the partition in the following manner:

```
num_partitions =  len(df.divisions)-1
print(num_partitions)
divs = [0]
for i in range(num_partitions):
    a = df.partitions[i].index.compute()
    divs.append(divs[-1]+a.stop)
    print(a)

print(divs)
df.divisions= divs
```

I am stuck at the point where I don't understand how to call the `df2 = df.set_index()` function. What should I be passing to this function to get indexing from 0-n?

Note: I don't want to convert to pandas and then convert it back since the file could be really large.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`dask.dataframe.reset_index`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.reset_index.html) docs:

> Note that unlike in `pandas`, the reset `dask.dataframe` index will not be monotonically increasing from `0`. Instead, it will restart at `0` for each partition (e.g. `index1 = [0, ..., 10], index2 = [0, ...]`). This is due to the inability to statically know the full length of the index.

This is the same reason why selecting rows with `iloc` is not supported, and why the index of a dataframe read with partitions is not monotonically increasing.

So, if you want to set such an index, you *have* to know the size of the dataframe. You could do this with `df_length = df.shape[0].compute()`, but note that this does require loading in all the data for a CSV.

Once you have this value, you can set the index with `df = df.set_index(range(df_length))`.